# Multilingual site: Why do I need the language "all"?

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, multilingual

I am creating a multilingual joomla site. At the moment I am working on the menu.

In every tutorial / template I see, they have a "Mainmenu" for every language they want to use and then there is a default "Mainmenu" for the language "ALL".

Since the default-language of my site is english (which also calls the english menu), why do I even need an "ALL"-menu? It's never called anyway, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 1.7, Joomla requires Home menu item for 'All' languages, as soon as you enable  System - Language Filter plugin and have Language Switcher module published. That menu item can be stored in any menu other than ones holding Home menu items for specific languages, even in hidden 'Virtual' menu.

I haven't been able to find precise or official documentation or explanation why is that needed, except that this **'Home - All' item will be visible before a user chooses any language (if a plugin doesn’t force a default language)**.

Anyway, it's just few clcks more to do, and I really don't need to know EXACTELY why is it needed, as long as multilingual setup works good, which it does ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to make sure everything is OK with my configuration.

Comment: You're quite welcome...